# Why does this user-defined literal not work?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following *does not* work on G++ 4.8.1 nor on 4.9:

```
constexpr double operator"" _sig (double sig)                               
{                                                                           
    return sig * 2.0;                                                      
}
```

> prog.cpp:4:49: error: ‘constexpr double operator"" _sig(double)’ has
>   invalid argument list
>        constexpr double operator"" _sig (double sig)

Oddly enough, the following *does* work:

```
constexpr long double operator"" _sig (long double sig)                               
{                                                                           
    return sig * 2.0;                                                      
}
```

Why??

Comment: @Mgetz hmm, maybe, but I've tried changing `sig` to something else, and using different names for the parameter as the literal name, still the same problem. I've even changed the type to `float`!

Comment: @PhilippLenk how do I make a user-defined literal for a signed integer then?

Comment: What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: I am not really sure, but i believe if it returns a used defined type you could overload unary minus on that. I dont think its possible with built in types(i could very well be wrong)

Comment: @PhilippLenk I asked a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430296/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-literal-for-a-signed-integer-type