# How do I create a user-defined literal for a signed integer type?

Tags: c++, c++11

As I discovered from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596864/c11-operator-with-double-parameter) the parameter types allowed for a user-defined literal type are as follows:

```
const char*
unsigned long long int
long double
char
wchar_t
char16_t
char32_t
const char*, std::size_t
const wchar_t*, std::size_t
const char16_t*, std::size_t
const char32_t*, std::size_t
```

Well, the only signed integer I see in that list is `char`, which is too small. What if I wanted to do something like this:

```
str operator"" _i(int i) {
    return i*2;
}
```

Then when I write `-1000_i` I expect to get `-2000`. How do I do this?

Comment: Sidenote: `char` may or may not be a signed type depending on implementation.

Comment: `char` (and `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t` apply to single-quoted character literals. A string of digits is always an integer literal and it is always positive, because the `-` sign is _not_ part of it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no such thing as a negative integer literal. `-1000` is the application of the unary `-` operator to the literal `1000`.

> Then when I write `-1000_i` I expect to get `-2000`. How do I do this?

Define `1000_i` in such a way that applying unary `-` gives `-2000`. You might for example make `1000_i` a structure type with a custom overloaded `operator-`.